# Stopping background service with change of activity in android

Tags: android, service, background

I have created a background service in android in java which plays music at the start of activity.

```
package com.sudarshan.tictactoenew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Service;

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return startId;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
//calling background service
Intent intent = new Intent(MenuPage.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

But this runs forever, I mean till the app is not closed.How do I stop this when I move to the next activity?I am calling background service in menupage activity

Comment: Use the activity life cycle event `onPause()` to stop the service and `onResume()` to restart it. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle